# Make a switch to add/remove a class to all elements that have a specific class

Tags: javascript, css

I've been trying to make a switch so when clicked it adds a class to every element that has the class "ChangeColors" but has been unable to do so.
It returns with

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

CSS

```
.ChangeColors {
    background-color: #ff801b;
    color:black;
}

.bluecolor {
 background-color: blue;
 color:white;
 }
```

Javascript

```
function ChangeColors() {
    var single = document.querySelector('.ChangeColors');
    var all = document.querySelectorAll('.ChangeColors');
    if (single.classList.contains('bluecolor')) {
      all.classList.remove('bluecolor');
      console.log("remove");
    } else {
      all.classList.add('bluecolor');
      console.log("add");
    }
}
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList. it won't have a property `classList`. You need to loop through the nodes and get the `classList` for each node one by one.

Comment: `var single = document.querySelector('.ChangeColors');` will return the first element. I am not sure you are targeting first element every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `.classList` on a `NodeList` type which is what `document.querySelectorAll` returns, you should instead be using that on every element inside the NodeList.

You can can actually use [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for this to avoid doing all the manual toggling like so.

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll('.ChangeColors');

all.forEach(elem => {
  elem.classList.toggle("bluecolor")
});
```

Comment: You kind sir, are an absolute legend! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function ChangeColors() {
    var single = document.querySelector('.ChangeColors');
    var all = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.ChangeColors')); // transform all to iterable array
    all.forEach(el => { // loop through and apply your condition to every element
      if (single.classList.contains('bluecolor')) {
        el.classList.remove('bluecolor');
        console.log("remove");
      } else {
        el.classList.add('bluecolor');
        console.log("add");
      }
    })
}
```